The set generates exactly n planes
We say that a set M of points in space generates a plane if there exist three non-collinear points from M that determine that plane. What are the natural numbers  n  for which there exists a set of  points in space such that no three of them are collinear, and the set generates exactly  n  planes?
My idea: $n\in \{1,4,5,6...\}$. For $n=1$ I consider 3 non-collinear points, and for $n$ greater than 3 I consider the vertices of a pyramid.

Note that a pyramid with 5 vertices (4 forming a qudraliteral in plane and one as the 'top') does generate 2 more planes than you account for, namely 2 planes generated by 2 opposing vertices of the quadraliteral and the 'top' vertex.
Generally, your approach with an $n$-side base polygon and a 'top' vertex will generate $1+{n \choose 2}$ planes, as like for $n=4$ above, the diagonals will create extra planes with the top vertices.

@Ingix but it is possible to obtain other numbers? For example it is possible to have exactly 8 planes?

That's not an easy question (I don't know the answer myself). I'd start with more possible configurations (say $n-2$ vertices in a plane, 2 outside in a line parallel to the plane) that give you more degrees of freedom to change the number (by controlling how many lines between 2 vertices in the plane are parallel to the outside line). I suspect that from some point on all numbers will be in $M$, but I have no intuition if that will be from 10, 100 or even larger numbers.

To clarify, do you want $n$ points to generate $n$ planes? (IE Same $n$ in both cases. Or are you asking for a much more general situation like "Can we have points that determine 8 planes", which was another question that you asked). $\quad$ If yes, show that If no 3 are collinear, then this can't be done as it's very restrictive. If we remove that condition, then take $n-2$ vertices in a line, and 2 points (A, B) not all coplanar with the other $n-2$ points. We get 1/ 1 plane from line + point A , 2/ 1 plane from line + point B, 3/ $n-2$ planes from point A + point B + 1 point from line.

@CalvinLin not exactly n points.

@CalvinLin thank you very much!!!

To see what $n$ can be accomplished without dropping the non-collinear rule:
Choose $k$ points, with no three collinear, and examine all the planes induced by the $\binom k3$ unordered trios from those points. Some planes are produced by a single trio, but others may be produced by two or more distinct trios. Since these trios are distinct, there are at least four or more points on the plane. Enumerate the redundant planes $\mathscr P_1, \dots, \mathscr P_q$, and for each $i$, let $m_i$ be the number of the $k$ chosen points which lie on $\mathscr P_i$. So each $m_i > 3$. Any two of the $\mathscr P_i$ may intersect in a line, which can contain at most two of the chosen points. So the sum of the $m_i$ may exceed $k$, but since the $m_i$ points are a subset of the $k$ points, and trios chosen from different planes must be distinct, we can be sure that $\binom k3 \ge \sum_{i=1}^q \binom{m_i}3$.
Since the planes produced by two distinct trios of the $k$ points can only be the same when all points in the two trios lie on the same $\mathscr P_i$, and there are $\binom{m_i}3$ trios obtainable from the points on $\mathscr P_i$, that plane will be produced $\binom{m_i}3$ in total. Thus the total number of distinct planes produced by trios of the $k$ points will be
$$n = q + \binom k3  - \sum_{i=1}^q \binom{m_i}3$$
I suspect if you make any choices for $k,q,m_1,\dots,m_q$ such that $\binom k3 \ge \sum_{i=1}^q \binom{m_i}3$, you should be able to find $k$ points in space with the desired properties. If so, then the problem reduces to what values can be expresses as $q + \binom k3  - \sum_{i=1}^q \binom{m_i}3$. I would not be surprised it there are only a finite number of values that cannot be so expressed.
